# How to get Duration in seconds from 2 columns dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a dataframe df as below:

| Station | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 05:10:00 |
| A456 | 26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 05:01:00 |

The data types for StartTime and EndTime are strings.
I would like to create another column with the duration from StartTime until EndTime.

| Station | StartTime | EndTime | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 05:10:00 PM | 600 |
| A456 | 26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 05:01:00 PM | 60 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
df['StartTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'].str.rsplit(n=1).str[0])
df['EndTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime'])
df['Duration']=df.eval("EndTime-StartTime").dt.total_seconds()
```

output of `df`:

```
   Station  StartTime            EndTime               Duration
0    A123   2021-05-26 05:00:00 2021-05-26 05:10:00     600.0
1    A456   2021-05-26 05:00:00 2021-05-26 05:01:00      60.0
```

**OR**

If you want to include `'AM'` and `'PM'` in `'StartTime'` then:

```
df['StartTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'])
df['EndTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime'])
df['Duration']=df.eval("EndTime-StartTime").dt.total_seconds()
```

output of `df`:

```
   Station  StartTime             EndTime              Duration
0    A123   2021-05-26 17:00:00  2021-05-26 05:10:00  -42600.0
1    A456   2021-05-26 17:00:00  2021-05-26 05:01:00  -43140.0
```

**Note:** If needed positive values then chain `abs()`

**OR**

If you doesn't want to change the initial format of your datelike columns:

```
df['Duration']=(pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'].str.replace('PM|AM',''))-pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime'])).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: You were too quick!

Comment: you *should* include AM/PM

Comment: @MrFuppes Sir but Op don't want AM and PM

Comment: I don't think the OP actually provided an example from which you can make that conclusion. Anyway, ignoring AM/PM if data is in that format gives invalid results, so I'd suggest a solution which doesn't do that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
a_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"Station": ["A1", "A2"], "ST": ["26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM", "26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM"], "ET":["26-MAY-2021 05:10:00. PM","26-MAY-2021 05:01:00 PM"]})

print(pd.to_datetime(a_dataframe['ET']) -pd.to_datetime(a_dataframe['ST']))
a_dataframe.insert(3, "Duration",pd.to_datetime(a_dataframe['ET']) -pd.to_datetime(a_dataframe['ST']))
print(a_dataframe)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you would have in mind?

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A123','26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM','26-MAY-2021 05:10:00 PM'], ['A456','26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM','26-MAY-2021 05:01:00 PM']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Station','StartTime','EndTime'])
df['StartTime'] =pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'])
df['EndTime'] =pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime'])
df['Duration'] = df['EndTime'] - df['StartTime']
```